# Unable to select individual parts of the mesh

Tags: modeling, mesh, export

I've been having issues when attempting to select parts of models. Due to the software I work in, I cannot export models as an entire part due to a poly limit. Whenever I attempt to select individual parts of the mesh, it selects the entire thing, rather than the body, headlights, etc, stuff I can pick out individually in Sketchup. I am importing into Blender .obj files and exporting in .obj files. I know I can go in and individually group faces, but that's a massive hassle for models that can be into the tens of thousands of faces. [image: In object mode, selects the whole model not individual parts]

Comment: One of the ways I can get around it is by selecting similar materials, but not all models I use have materials applied, so a solution is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your model consists of multiple meshes, you can

- Select all other faces of the mesh using *Select > Select Linked > Linked*, <kbd>Ctrl + L</kbd>
- Then separate the selected faces through *Mesh > Separate > Selection*, <kbd>P</kbd>
- Or make each mesh into a separate object through *Mesh > Separate > By Loose Parts*, <kbd>P</kbd>

[image]

[image]